# How to get the deltas of a list collection

Tags: c#, collections

I have a list.

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

I wish to return a list of differences (deltas) between consecutive element.

> 1 1 1 1 1 1

How can I do this?

I am sure there must be a simple "collections" way of doing this - but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Skip` and the overload of [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) which projects the index:

```
List<int> deltaList = list.Skip(1)             // skip first, irrelevant
    .Select((num, index) => num - list[index]) // index 0 is second number in list
    .ToList();
```

The trick is that `Skip(1)` does not only skip the first number (which is desired) but also changes the indices in `Select`. The first number's `index` will be 0 but it'll refer to the second number in the list (due to `Skip(1)`). Therefore `num - list[index]` subtracts the current with the previous number.

Comment: That's great. But can you please explain it a little. Why is num assigned to current element? Is index a key word?

Comment: @ManInMoon: i have commented it. It's just ignoring the first item and starts with the second. Then it's subtracting  the last number from the current in the list. Finally it creates a new list.

Comment: @ManInMoon `(num, index) => num - list[index]` is a delegate, an anonymous method that takes two arguments, `num` and `index`. The `Select` method will then call your delegate and fill in the variables for those arguments, setting the first argument to the current element of the collection and the second argument to that element's position in the collection. The names of the arguments could be anything, they're not keywords - they could be `x` and `y` instead, but `num` and `index` describe their purpose better.

Comment: Here's the documentation for `Select`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: WHy do I get "index out of range error"?

if (B.Count < 3)
                return;

            List<double> deltaList = B.Skip(1)
                .Select((num, index) => num.close - B[index - 1].close)
                .ToList();

Comment: @ManInMoon: because you are not using my code (compare `B[index - 1]` with `list[index]`).

Comment: I thought I was - I had to add a "close" because that's what is in my class.

Comment: @ManInMoon: you still don't see it? I'm using `B[index]` instead of `B[index - 1]`. And i've also explained in my answer why that works.

Comment: I do see BUT how do I tell index to refer to previous element - not current? Surely skip(1) applies to index AND num?

Comment: @ManInMoon: but `B[index]` _is_ the previous element in the list because `index` starts with the second item due to `Skip(1)`. So `num` is the current item and `B[index]` is the last.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63706/discussion-between-maninmoon-and-tim-schmelter).

Comment: For anyone else reading this an confused as I WAS. The thing to note is that the second "list" does not have the skip(1) part.

Comment: For those who still don't get it, paste this into LINQPAD to see the state at each iteration: `List<int> demo = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
demo.Skip(1).Select ((abf_num,abf_index) => new{Result=abf_num - demo[abf_index],Abf_Num = abf_num,listindex=abf_index,listnum=demo[abf_index]}).ToList().Dump();`.  `Result` is the difference (the stuff Tim is returning), `Abf_Num` is the minuend,`listnum` is the subtrahend, and `listindex` is the index of the subtrahend in the original list.  The more important part of this comment is the strategy it demonstrates for teasing out simple LINQ.

Comment: `List<int> demo = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
demo.Skip(1).Select ((abf_num,abf_index) => String.Format("{0}-{1} (demo[{2}] is {1}) == {3}",abf_num,demo[abf_index],abf_index,abf_num-demo[abf_index])).ToList().Dump();`
 is easier to read :).

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (x, y) => y - x);
```